# zsh conditional statement help

Tags: command-line, zsh

Feeling kinda dumb right now:

Why is my contional always true?

I've tried

```
# this should let me know what's not a directory or 
# symbolic link.
whoa=`find ${MUSICDIR} ! -type l ! -type d | wc -l`

# I would expect if it's 0 (meaning nothing was found) that
# one of these statements would evaluate to false, but so far
# it's always evaluating to true
if [[ "${whoa}" != "0" ]]
    do something
fi
if [[ ${whoa} -gt 0 ]]
    do something
fi
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

turns out, i was missing the "then" after the if statement.

should be

```
if [[ "${whoa}" != "0" ]]
then
    do something
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The backticks collect stdout of the subprocess, and `whoa` will contain the text, not the errorlevel. You can use `$?` to get the errorlevel of the last command.

But if you're using find you can use its `exec` feature to do something.

Also, you can use type `f` for file, to find a regular file.

Comment: turns out, i was missing the "then" after the if statement.   I know i can use "-type f", and I probably should.   Just just nervous i'll miss something else.   Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: @Dennis meta question: if you post a question and answer it yourself do you get points?

Comment: Not from yourself, but others can upvote your question and your answe.